# Avoid iterating when returning a redis list with objects

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I'm saving a JSON.stringified version of an object to a Redis List. I need to use lists because I'm using LPUSH / RPUSH and LTRIM.

The problem is that node_redis is saving a escaped version of my stringified object, so when I retrieve the list range I can't parse the whole list, I have to iterate trough the list and parse each of the items in the list.

Is there a way to parse the whole list when retrieving it without iterating the whole list?

Answer (score 1):

Lists are typically always required to iterate over. It's part of the definition.

Can you store your json-object as a String in Redis instead?

Comment: It's stored as a string using `JSON.stringify(obj)`

Comment: I didn't explain myself I guess, I'm still using lists but storing the object as a string in my list. Since I have a bunch of objects I need lists.

Comment: You should probably not store the data itself in the list, instead use is as an index, lists are typically used for queues, timelines and messaging. Have you IDs in the list and point to the data elsewhere.